# Hue tables not visible

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hue

Not able to see the tables under database when user1 login to hue(circle keeps rotating) but user 2 can see. both users are in the same group.

Logout and login didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

It was broweser cache issue. I used hue through Private mode(firefox) or incognito mode(Chrome) and it showed all the tables.

Comment: Hue also has a little circle icon in the SQL Assist to refresh all the table metadata.